# Obtain Kaplan-Meier survival risk per individual instance

Tags: r, data-mining, probability, survival-analysis

#### Problem

Given *n*-patient records with `time` and `status` variables (among others), I would like to obtain their survival risk in the time period they're within ie 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 years.

I have a division of 24 - 47 months (2 years), 48 - 83 months (4 years), 84 - 107 months (6 years), 108 - 119 months (8 years) and 120 - "up to what's available" months (10 years).

In an individual perspective, a patient with survival months of 30 months will be included in the two-year period and along with the other predictive variables I want to know this patient's survival risk within two years.

#### My method

I'm retrieving survival risk percentages for my data using the [R code described in this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/26291/35842).

```
km <- survfit(Surv(time, status)~1, data=mydata)
survest <- stepfun(km$time, c(1, km$surv))
```

The `time` variable is the survival months and the `status` has values `1` and `0` for alive and dead respectively.

The code outputs something like this (taken from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/26291/35842)):

```
> survest(0:100)
 [1] 1.0000000 0.9854015 0.9781022 0.9708029 0.9635036 0.9635036 0.9635036
 [8] 0.9416058 0.9124088 0.9124088 0.8978102 0.8905109 0.8759124 0.8613139
 [15] 0.8613139 0.8467153 0.8394161 0.8394161 0.8175182 0.8029197 0.7883212
 [22] 0.7737226 0.7664234 0.7664234 0.7518248 0.7299270 0.7299270 0.7225540
 [29] 0.7225540 0.7151810 0.7004350 0.6856890 0.6856890 0.6783160 0.6783160
```

My question is: are these the actual survival estimates for my 300,000 individual records wherein I need to use `survest(0:300000)`? I tried `survest(0:1000)` but the result already converged to some value and this does not answer my problem.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you correctly: are you trying to get KM-estimates for the population or for individual patients? I don't think it is possible to get KM-estimates for individual patients as the KM-estimator gives the observed probability of survival at a certain timepoint on a population level. The 'observed risk' for an individual is either 0 (alive) or 1 (death). To get a predicted survival probability for an individual you would have to use some sort of model. The code you provide gives KM-estimates on a population level for different timepoints.

Comment: @Rob, I'm trying to get KM-estimates for individual patients. Do you know how can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, I don't think it is possible to get KM-estimates for individual patients. The KM-estimator gives the observed probability of survival at a certain timepoint on a population level. The observed survival probability for an individual, however, is either 0 (death) or 1 (alive), nothing in between.

Instead of observed survival probabilities you will have to use some sort of model (e.g. Cox PH, accelerated failure time model, neural network etc.) to get predicted survival probabilities. These probabilities inform you about the risk of an individual with that particular variable combination to be alive at a particular timepoint.

UPDATE: with example code based on code the OP provided [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80049/obtaining-r-pec-survival-patient-risk-percentage)

```
library(pec) ; library(rms)

# Simulate data
set.seed(1)
examp.data <- SimSurv(3000)

# fit a Cox model with predictors X1+X2
coxmodel <- cph(Surv(time,status)~X1+X2, data=examp.data, surv=TRUE) 

# predicted survival probabilities can be extracted at selected time-points:
ttt <- quantile(examp.data$time)
ttt
#          0%          25%          50%          75%         100% 
#6.959458e-03 9.505409e+00 3.077284e+01 7.384565e+01 7.100556e+02 

# Get predicted survival probabilities at selected time-points:
preds <- predictSurvProb(coxmodel, newdata=examp.data, times=ttt)

# Store in original data
examp.data$predict.surv.prob.Q1 <- preds[,1] # pred. surv. prob. at  0.006959458
examp.data$predict.surv.prob.Q2 <- preds[,2] # pred. surv. prob. at  9.505409
examp.data$predict.surv.prob.Q3 <- preds[,3] # pred. surv. prob. at  30.77284
examp.data$predict.surv.prob.Q4 <- preds[,4] # pred. surv. prob. at  73.84565
examp.data$predict.surv.prob.Q5 <- preds[,5] # pred. surv. prob. at  710.0556
```

Now you have predictions of the survival probabilities at those 5 timepoints for each individual in your data. Of course, you do need to evaluate the predictive performance of your model in terms of discrimination (e.g. with the function `cindex` in pec-package) and calibration (with calibration plot, see rms-package).

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you expound on the models that I can utilize though like possible R functions? I'm planning to use WEKA and use my individual patient risks as the outcome variable but I can't right now because I don't have that variable yet.

Comment: just for confirmation, the `X1+X2+...+Xn` refers to the other (appropriate) predictive variables in the dataset right?

Comment: another one, `quantile(data$time)` confuses me - which of these are the actual *time points* (ie values of the variable `time`)? The percentages or the decimal values?

Comment: @llorgge Indeed, the X1+X2 are the predictors in the dataset. If you want the best predictions possible in your specific dataset you may want to add all potential predictors, however if your goal is to use the model in new datasets or for real life patients, you should account for overoptimism. For details see the book of [Steyerberg](http://www.clinicalpredictionmodels.org/), which is really helpful for prediction research.

Comment: @llorgge Regarding the quantiles: I just took your example. Those are indeed actual timepoints (in this case in quintiles). If I were you I would take more (clinically) relevant timepoints, such as the timepoint you mention in your question 2,4,6,8,10 years, which you can fill in in the `times` argument as `c(2,4,6,8,10)` (if the scale of the `time` variable in your dataset is in years of course).

Comment: You could also just use the months, but if you want to change it to years, I would not change it to the years they are within range of, since then you would loose some information. Just divide it by 12. The  25% in the quintiles mean that 25% of the survival times in your dataset are below that value. E.g. for the example in my answer: 25% of individuals have a time lower than 9.505409, 50% below 30.77284, etc.

Comment: Last one, in the output of `preds`, these five columns refer to the record's survival rate per timepoint right?

Comment: Yep, each column contains the individual survival probabilities for each person in the data, with separate columns for the different timepoints.

Comment: Can someone please take a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65137064/r-plotting-roc-curves-without-the-pec-library thanks!